# How do I copy a file over FTP using Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

I'm using [Ubuntu Software Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center) 2.0.7, and I would like to copy a file from this machine over FTP. Can you please help me how to do it?

I know in Windows I just open a [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer) window and type *ftp.www.mysite.com*. Then it will ask for the user name and password.

I would like to do the same in my Ubuntu Linux, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to open a terminal and use wget:

```
$ wget ftp://ftp.mysite.com/path/to/file
```

You need to replace "path/to/file/ with the [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29) of the file you want to download. That is, the address where the file is found on the disk. So, to get a file called file.txt that is in sub directory foo of directory bar, you would write:

```
$ wget ftp://ftp.mysite.com/foo/bar/file.txt
```

If your ftp server requires a username and password:

```
$ wget ftp://username:password@ftp.mysite.com/foo/bar/file.txt
```

Replacing "username" and "password" with your actual username and password. **Do not include the `$` in any of these commands**.

From the wget man page:

> GNU Wget is a free utility for non-interactive download of files from
>          the Web.  It supports HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP protocols, as well as
>          retrieval through HTTP proxies.

---

You can also use ftp from the command line:

```
$ ftp ftp.mysite.com
```

Enter your user name and password, then use `put` to upload the file:

```
ftp>put local_file remote_file
```

For example:

```
ftp>put Downloads/List/Song.mp3 Song.mp3
```

Do not include the `ftp>` in your command. That just indicates the `ftp` prompt.

---

Finally, you either use a normal browser (eg firefox) or install a graphical ftp client. My personal favorite is gftp:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gftp
```

Oh, and you are not using Ubuntu Software Center 2.0.7. That is just Ubuntu's software management app.

---

**Note on terminology**

When a terminal command is given, the symbol `$` is used to indicate that it is a terminal command. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/57575/what-is-the-origin-of-the-unix-dollar-prompt) for a discussion. It is not part of the actuall command. So, to tell you to run the command ls, I would write `$ ls`. You, however, should only type `ls`, without the `$`.

Comment: Thanks for the 3 suggestions. I tried the first one, I opened the terminal and it says: "name@ubuntu@desktop: ~ $" then I entered "$ wget ftp://ftp.mysite.com/path/to/file" it says Login incorrect. Do I need to include the "/path/to/file" I don't understand this bit. Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering how to copy it to the ftp server if it's in the root. Can I write it like this: "ftp> get /Downloads/FolderA/Song.mp3/to/root"

Comment: @tintincutes Sorry, I forgot you are new to Linux. I have updated my anwer.

Comment: Thanks. But I always get a message not a directory. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @tintincutes using which command? Since you are not comfortable with the terminal, why don't you use firefox? Or, better, install gftp?

Comment: Thanks a for the edit message. Btw, I used your 2nd suggestion and not the first one because it was quite difficult.So I opened my command line and I got to the point "User "user" logged. Remote system type is Unix. Using Binary mode to transfer files." I just wanted to upload the file from the linux machine to my ftp server. Is that possible?

Comment: @tintincutes Use the graphical ftp client (`sudo apt-get install gftp; gftp`. Anyway, I updated the answer to include the `put` command.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4635/discussion-between-terdon-and-tintincutes)

Comment: I'm on the chatroom you created. Are you still there?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but `wget username:password@ftp://ftp.mysite.com/foo/bar/file.txt` should read `wget ftp://username:password@ftp.mysite.com/foo/bar/file.txt`

Comment: @Brian d'oh! Of course it should, thanks for pointing it out. Answer edited.

Comment: Does it automatically use passive transfer mode?

Answer (score 1):

In Nautilus or Firefox, you can input in the address bar:

```
ftp://username@ftp.server.com
```